# "net use" command in a Windows Service

Tags: .net, windows-services

We're using the following command line from within a Windows Service developed with C# .Net Framework 1.1:

```
net use z: \\myComputer\c$
```

The service is running under a domain account that is a local administrator on "myComputer". After debugging the code we can see that it does not return any errors but the "z:" drive is never mapped. We've tried the exact same code from a console application and it works properly. What is it that we need to add to the Service to make this work?

The code we're using is included below.

Regards,
Sergio

```
startInfo.FileName = "net";  
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"use {0}: \\{1}\{2}", driveLetter,
                                    computerName, folder).Trim();  
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;  
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;  
proc.StartInfo = startInfo;

proc.Start();

// If there is an error during the mapping of the drive, it will be read
// from the StandardError property which is a StreamReader object and
// be fed into the error output parameter.  
using(StreamReader errorReader = proc.StandardError)  
{  
         string standardError = string.Empty;  
    while((standardError = errorReader.ReadLine()) != null)  
    {  
        error += standardError + " ";  
    }  
}  
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 18):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685143.aspx:

> A service (or any process running in a
>   different security context) that must
>   access a remote resource should use
>   the Universal Naming Convention (UNC)
>   name to access the resource. The
>   service must have appropriate
>   privileges to access the resource. If
>   a server-side service uses an RPC
>   connection, delegation must be enabled
>   on the remote server.
>
> Drive letters are not global to the
>   system. Each logon session receives
>   its own set of drive letters from A to
>   Z. Therefore, redirected drives cannot
>   be shared between processes running
>   under different user accounts.
>   Moreover, a service (or any process
>   running within its own logon session)
>   cannot access the drive letters that
>   were established within a different
>   logon session.
>
> A service should not directly access
>   local or network resources through
>   mapped drive letters, nor should it
>   call the net use command to map drive
>   letters at run time.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access user properties from a windows service (including the HKEY-CURRENT-USER from the registry) because the service does not run as a logged in user.

Mapped drives are part of user settings, so you cannot use them as a service unless you dig through to find the user properties in the registry manually, map the drives in your service, etc.  It's a pain.

What you may want to try and do is ask a question about how to have your Service execute the login sequence (probably some .EXE).  That may do it for you.

Hope this helps,
Alan.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify the account used for the login.  Type `net use /?` on a command prompt to get help setting that up with the command.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it is because the service is not running in the context of the local user. As I remember, you can configure a windows service from years-ago to 'interact with the desktop' or something similar.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adioltean/2004/11/29/launching-a-cmd-window-as-local-system/

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar to log in to a remote server, but without the mapped drive part. I don't like using mapped drives; in programs that is, I use subst for convenience all the time.
Anyway, I just had to make sure to include

```
use \\server\c$ /user:admin password
```

or whatever your user/password is that has access to the remote server, then it doesn't matter what the service is logged on as.